# error stating blank fields when trying to create events and fields not blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I get "3 errors prohibited this event from being saved:Title can't be blank Date can't be blank Description can't be blank. it was working perfectly but not sure whats wrong with it now?

When they are not even blank?

here is the controller.

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, :only => [:create , :destroy]
  before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /events
  # GET /events.json
  def index
    @events = Event.all
  end

  # GET /events/1
  # GET /events/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /events/new
  def new
    @event = Event.new
  end



 # GET /events/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /events
  # POST /events.json
  def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /events/1
  # PATCH/PUT /events/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.update(event_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /events/1
  # DELETE /events/1.json
  def destroy
    @event.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to events_url, notice: 'Event was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_event
      @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:title, :date, :description)
    end
end
```

Here is the form:

```
<%= form_for(@event) do |f| %>
  <% if @event.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@event.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this event from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @event.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :date %><br>
    <%= f.date_select :date %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

model code as per request :

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title , :date,  :description
  validates_uniqueness_of :title 
end
```

Comment: did you check the params hash...is the params correct...can you also post the model code...specially the validation part.

Comment: can you post parameters sent to server from your terminal?

Comment: i've now posted the model code

Comment: As suggested from Surya, can you paste te log output for the request?

Comment: the routes may also be useful

Comment: If this code was "working perfectly" before and it suddenly isn't working then the change you've made to break it is somewhere else. You know what the error is: data in 3 fields is blank. That is what your change is related to. When you find it, either update your question or delete it, depending on what the change was.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with one of the gems I have installed which I have now  removed. working now.